# Setting active links in Jekyll not working

Tags: html, css, yaml, jekyll

I am trying to simply style my active links in Jekyll but have been unsuccessful in getting them working.

Here is the site that I am trying to get them working on: http://concisecss.github.io/concise.css, which you can see the source code for here: https://github.com/ConciseCSS/concise.css/tree/gh-pages.

I am putting this YAML code in my `_config.yml` to define my top-level navigation:

```
# Main Navigation
nav:
- text: Welcome
  url: /concise.css/
- text: Why Concise
  url: /concise.css/why-concise/
- text: Get Started
  url: /concise.css/get-started/
- text: Documentation
  url: /concise.css/documentation/layout/container/
- text: Add-Ons
  url: /concise.css/add-ons/
```

Then in my `header.html` include, which is where my navigation is, I have:

```
{% for link in site.nav %}
  <li>
    <a {% if link.url == page.url %}class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.text }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

However, whenever I am on one of those navigation links, the active class is not added (the link should be pinkish when you are on it.

Everything else is working fine, so I'm assuming it might just be a small issue I'm running into.

**Edit:** Here is what the front-matter on one of my pages looks like:

```
---
layout: why-concise
title: Why Concise
permalink: /why-concise/
---
```

Comment: Are you setting the permalink in your individual page YAML?
( permalink: /concise.css/why-concise/ )

Comment: Yes! I just added that to the question description.

Comment: Ah I see, would it have to do with you're loop being set to build the class with the link.url? so when the _config.yml link.url is set to /concise.css/why-concise/ it doesn't match the page YAML of /why-concise/

Comment: Huh, I think I understand. Are you suggesting I change the YAML in my `why-concise.html` to: `permalink: /concise.css/why-concise/` (sorry, I'm just learning how to use Jekyll and YAML so a lot of this is new to me)?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, if you're going to set a permalink of your individual pages it needs to be exactly the same as the variables of your _config.yml if that loop is going to work.  If you're not running jekyll serve --watch, you might also need to re run jekyll to have it parse the changes to the YAML - depending on which version you have.

Comment: Try adding permalink: /concise.css/documentation/layout/container/ to your documentation's page YAML and see if that works

Comment: I tried adding that but for some reason the page won't even show up now: http://concisecss.github.io/concise.css/documentation/layout/container/

Comment: I think once I switch the project page to http://concisecss.github.io/ it will fix the issues, since I won't have to worry about the `/concise.css/` part of the URL...

Comment: Yes, it did fix it: http://concisecss.github.io/get-started/. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

I just did the same thing in my blog project which is not alive yet to show you, but it works like this:

**1.** create a data file `nav.yml` file and write your nav text and URLs within a folder [_data](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/).

## nav.yml

```
- text: Welcome
  url: /concise.css/

- text: Why Concise
  url: /concise.css/why-concise/

- text: Get Started
  url: /concise.css/get-started/

- text: Documentation
  url: /concise.css/documentation/layout/container/

- text: Add-Ons
  url: /concise.css/add-ons/
```

**2.** In your html page you're going to create a loop through your data menu list from yml file.

```
{% for nav in site.data.nav %}
<li{% if nav.url == page.url %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ nav.url }}">{{ nav.text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Just remember to make sure your permalink is the same written in your nav.yml if you have set `url:/concise.css/why-concise/` in your nav.yml so your permalink should be the same in the front-matter.

```
---
layout: why-concise
title: Why Concise
permalink: /concise.css/why-concise/
---
```

UPDATE:
@Keenan here is an example http://adrianorosa.com, that I told you before.
The source can be found at https://github.com/adrianorsouza/adrianorosa.com

Comment: Kudos on the active class hack!

Comment: how would you retain the route match for other post urls?

Comment: @cameronjroe sorry I didn't understand your question very well , but I think you meant to how to do the same for others post. So you have set the permalink for each post the jekyll build take care of the rest. I just updated my answer above with an example and the source code if you want to look at and get inspired.

Answer (score 0):

### Sep 2023

I believe this question is resolved.
It's 2023, and we still have this issue. So, if anyone is looking for a solution, here it is.

I am using `ruby 3.3.2` and `jekyll 4.3.2`

## DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself

`.md` files are converted to `.html` when they compile.
Let's start with simple navigation.
I have created three menus in the _config.yml file.

```yaml
nav:
- title: Home
  url: /
- title: About
  url: /about/
- title: Contact
  url: /contact/
```

### Frontend

After compiling, this is how it looks.
Even though the pages all work fine, if you notice, none of the files have the `.html` extension.

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

### Original URL

If you output `{{ page.url }}`, you will see `.html` attached to each of the links.

```
/
/contact.html
/about.html
```

### Issue

What you are doing here is comparing `/pagename/` to `/pagename.html`. How will this work?
It will work only on the homepage because the homepage for both **page.url** and **link.url** is a slash `/`.

So, How to fix this?

### Solution 1

You have to include `.html` in all the URLs.
This will fix the issue.

```
# Main Navigation
nav:
- text: Home
  url: /
- text: About
  url: /about.html
- text: Contact
  url: /contact.html
```

### Solution 2

If you have a simple site, you could output all the pages directly using `site.pages`. Since all the pages have a 'title', you can use that property. But before that, let's output all of them by URL.

#### Output all `url`

```html
<ol>
    {% for key in site.pages %}
        <li>{{key.url}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Notice that all the URLs have `.html` attached, except for the fourth one, which is 'Home'.

```
<ol>
    <li>/404.html</li>
    <li>/about.html</li>
    <li>/contact.html</li>
    <li>/</li>
    <li>/assets/main.css</li>
    <li>/feed.xml</li>
</ol>
```

#### Output by `title`

Let's output all the **titles** for the pages. I am assuming all the **titles** are set in the Front Matter.

```html
<ol>
    {% for key in site.pages %}
        <li>{{key.title}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Notice that some of the files do not have a title. The ones that have the title are needed for the website.

```html
<ol>
    <li></li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
```

#### Filter by `title`

Now let's use an `if` condition to filter the files that have a **title**.

```html
<ol>
    {% for key in site.pages %}
    {% if key.title %}
        <li>{{key.title}}</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

This outputs the following

```html
<ol>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Home</li>
</ol>
```

### Conclusion

Here's the final menu.
Now you can use the `active` class condition; it should work on all menus.

```html
<ol>
    <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
</ol>
```